# How to make columns of a table resizable with CSS without property of table width 100%

Tags: html, css, resize

This question is similar to that you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73155137/how-to-make-columns-of-a-100-width-html-table-resizable-causing-cut-off-text-t)
Would it be possible to do the same without using width 100%?

I have a large table and I want to keep it scrollable horizontally without squeezing other columns as I enlarge one...

Thank you so much!

Comment: just do a change to the value  `min-with` on the first cell of choosed column..

Comment: Hi @MisterJojo, thanks for your answer! I tried doing that but the other columns still shrink when I enlarge the first... I would like them to move right instead of shrinking

Comment: remove the global table with, put a min with on any td head column